# PHP - How to make app read beautified locale uri parameter?

Tags: php, localization, locale

So instead of `www.example.com?locale=en`, I want to have `www.example.com/en/` (or any other country code like `de`, `nl`...), so that locale part of uri is available in PHP code, so I could use it to determine in what language content should be displayed.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: This is pretty broad.  You can do this rule directly using mod_rewrite and a rewriterule, but that has nothing to do with PHP.  If you're using PHP, you'd likely want a routing solution that is included in many frameworks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart way to add language to all website URLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446273/smart-way-to-add-language-to-all-website-urls)

Comment: FYI: I did a super quick google search for this and found many examples. Maybe start there?